# inside comparatore interface's compare method also uses comparable interface's comapareTo method to compare string

Tags: java, collections

I have Customer class, it has customer_name string field, And I have a collection which holds customer class.

To sort the collection Comparator implemented and overriding

```
public int  compare(Customer cus1,Cuomer cus2){
   return cus1.cusomer_name.compareTo(cus2.cusomer_name); //my question here
}
```

in compare method I used to call String's compareTO() method.

Is compareTo() only way to compare string? if yes why?

Comment: Why do you expect Java to have two different methods that do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

> Is compareTo() only way to compare string? if yes why?

No, it is not only way. You can manually maintain the `compareTo` contract by returning 0, (+) value and (-)value.